# Checkox binding in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I am trying to create a simple checkbox using reactJS and trying to bind the state of the checkbox using `handlecheck()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Getting Started with React</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='react-container'></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    
    class Checkbox extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          checked: false
        }
        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)
      }

      handleCheck(){
        this.setState ({
          checked: true
        })
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <input type = "checkbox"/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Checkbox />,
      document.getElementById("react-container")
    )
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But, here even though I am using

```
handleCheck(){
                this.setState ({
                  checked: true
                })
              }
```

I am still able to check and uncheck the box multiple time, but in reality, it shouldn't as it has to check it once and should stop.
I know that in the actual scenario it should be something like:

```
handleCheck(){
            this.setState ({
              checked: !this.state.checked
            })
          }
```

Can someone tell me why am I able to check and uncheck multiple times even though I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), which needs a handler to change the state, and it's value/checked properties are controlled by the state.

You need to assign `this.handleCheck` as the `onChange` handler, and `this.state.checked` as the `checked` property value:

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)
  }

  handleCheck() {
    this.setState({
      checked: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.handleCheck}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Checkbox /> ,
  document.getElementById("react-container")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='react-container'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `handleCheck` to your checkbox

```
<div>
  <input type = "checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} checked={this.state.checked}/>
</div>
```